# How do I select the last dte in MySql WHERE NOT EXIST

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, subquery, max

I am testing in a PHP web application if a user has logged in, in the last three months. If the user has not logged in, I send a reminder email to the user. I have a code that does work, except for the fact that the code selects the first date in the database (MySql), and not the last one.

**Here is some sample data:**
All login dates for test user:

[image]

SQL select the first date instead of the last date:

[image]

I expected to see the date `2020-06-21`

This is my last code attempt:

```
SELECT Client, IP, Date
FROM iplog ip1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM iplog ip2 
              WHERE ip1.Client = ip2.Client AND
                    ip2.Date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)ORDER BY Date DESC)
                    GROUP BY Client
                    ORDER BY Date DESC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't it simpler done with aggregation?

```
select client, max(date) last_login_date
from iplog 
group by client
having max(date) <= now() - interval 3 month
```

This brings the clients that did not login during the last 3 months, along with their last login date.

Note that this query can *not* identify clients that *never* logged in (because they do not appear in the log table). In normal situations, you would have a separate table that stores the clients, and then:

```
select c.*
from clients c
where not exists (
    select 1 from iplog l where l.client = c.client and l.date > now() - interval 3 month
)
```